# Using dplyr:filter to create new variables in for loop for rMarkdown

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, r-markdown, filtering

I have some R code that is meant to run a .rmd file so that I can create a unique report for multiple individuals at the same time.

Simplistically, my issue is that code chunk 1 creates a PDF output that is correct, however, will only create one PDF, and not one for each athlete in my dataset.

Code chunk 2 will create multiple PDF outputs (one for each athlete in the dataset), however, the variables created within the for loop (i.e., Athlete_full_name_i, Athlete_Sport_i) do not work. In the PDF output, these values are presented as "c("values","in","the","list")".

I think the code is close to working well but I would Love some advice to make this run smoother.

Thank you!

code chunk 1:

'''

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)

 #extra information
Folder_path1 <- "path to folder"
Excel_sheet1 <- "Data"
StartDate1 <- "2021-09-01"
EndDate1 <- Sys.Date()

#create athlete dataframe to run one, or multiple athlete reports at once. 
Athlete_full_name <- c("John Smith", "Joe Tree") #as the name should appear in the report
Athlete_file_name <- c("SmithJ", "TreeJ") #Last name, first initial 
Athlete_Team <- c("Men's Football", "Men's Darts") #Sport as it should appear in the report

 Athlete_df <- data.frame(Athlete_full_name, Athlete_file_name, Athlete_Team)
 Names <- unique(Athlete_df$Athlete_file_name)

 #For loop - each athlete in Athlete_df gets unique report

 for (i in 1:length(Names)) {
   #creating new variables for each iteration

   #determine athlete full name
    Athlete_full_name_i <- Athlete_df %>% 
                           filter(Athlete_file_name == Names[i]) %>% 
                           subset(select = 1)

#determine athlete sport
   Athlete_Sport_i <-    Athlete_df %>% 
                         filter(Athlete_file_name == Names[i]) %>% 
                         subset(select = 3)

 #create Athlete report with unique params and unique filename
   rmarkdown::render("R2S_Dinos_JumpV3.Rmd", 
                 params = list(Athlete_csvname = Names[i],
                               Athlete_fullname = Athlete_full_name_i,
                               Team = Athlete_Sport_i,
                               Folder_path = Folder_path1,
                               Excel_sheet = Excel_sheet1,
                               StartDate = StartDate1,
                               EndDate = EndDate1),
                output_format = "pdf_document",
                output_file=paste0("Athlete Reports/", Names[i], "_Report_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"))
 }
```

'''

code chunk 2:

'''

'''

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)

 #extra information
Folder_path1 <- "path to folder"
Excel_sheet1 <- "Data"
StartDate1 <- "2021-09-01"
EndDate1 <- Sys.Date()

#create athlete dataframe to run one, or multiple athlete reports at once. 
Athlete_full_name <- c("John Smith", "Joe Tree") #as the name should appear in the report
Athlete_file_name <- c("SmithJ", "TreeJ") #Last name, first initial 
Athlete_Team <- c("Men's Football", "Men's Darts") #Sport as it should appear in the report

 Athlete_df <- data.frame(Athlete_full_name, Athlete_file_name, Athlete_Team)
 

 #For loop - each athlete in Athlete_df gets unique report

 for (Athlete_file_name in Athlete_df$Athlete_file_name) {
   #creating new variables for each iteration

   #determine athlete full name
    Athlete_full_name_i <- Athlete_df %>% 
                           filter(Athlete_file_name == Athlete_file_name) %>% 
                           subset(select = 1)

#determine athlete sport
   Athlete_Sport_i <-    Athlete_df %>% 
                         filter(Athlete_file_name == Athlete_file_name) %>% 
                         subset(select = 3)

 #create Athlete report with unique params and unique filename
   rmarkdown::render("R2S_Dinos_JumpV3.Rmd", 
                 params = list(Athlete_csvname = Athlete_file_name,
                               Athlete_fullname = Athlete_full_name_i,
                               Team = Athlete_Sport_i,
                               Folder_path = Folder_path1,
                               Excel_sheet = Excel_sheet1,
                               StartDate = StartDate1,
                               EndDate = EndDate1),
                output_format = "pdf_document",
                output_file=paste0("Athlete Reports/", Athlete_file_name, "_Report_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"))
 }
```

'''

Comment: *"Using dplyr:filter to create new variables"*. That function is only used to choose which _rows_ to retain, it has nothing to do with making variables.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the response. I agree that dplyr:filter does not create new variables per se. However, in the above example, it is used along with the pipe operator to create variables. Is there a better method to achieve my desired result?

Comment: (1) You're using `%>%` and `filter`, why are you using `subset` instead of `select`? It seems inconsistent. (2) `subset(select = 3)` returns a `data.frame`, are you expecting it to return a vector or single-value? Perhaps you want `pull(3)` (and other numbers) instead. (3) Other than that ... that's all I can see.

Answer (score 0):

When I run Code chunk 1 with a test Rmd output file it works as expected (two pdf files):

*test_out.Rmd* file:

```
---
title: "test_out"
params:
  name: Bob
  personid: 1
---

`r params$name` is person number `r params$personid`
```

Shortened slightly for clarity:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)

Athlete_full_name <- c("John Smith", "Joe Tree")
Athlete_file_name <- c("SmithJ", "TreeJ")
Athlete_Team <- c("Men's Football", "Men's Darts")

Athlete_df <- data.frame(Athlete_full_name, Athlete_file_name, Athlete_Team)

Names <- unique(Athlete_df$Athlete_file_name)

for (i in 1:length(Names)) {
  Athlete_full_name_i <- Athlete_df %>%
    filter(Athlete_file_name == Names[i]) %>%
    subset(select = 1)
  
  Athlete_Sport_i <-    Athlete_df %>%
    filter(Athlete_file_name == Names[i]) %>%
    subset(select = 3)
  
  rmarkdown::render(
    "test_out.Rmd",
    params = list(Athlete_fullname = Athlete_full_name_i,
                  Team = Athlete_Sport_i),
    output_format = "pdf_document",
    output_file = paste0("test_out/", Names[i], "_Report_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
  )
}
```

You could make this tidier and easier to debug with an anonymous function inside `group_walk` - this is the way I'd recommend doing it:

```r
Athlete_df |>
  rowwise() |>
  group_walk(function(data, key) {
    rmarkdown::render(
      "test_out.Rmd",
      params = list(
        Athlete_fullname = data$Athlete_full_name,
        Team = data$Athlete_Team
      ),
      output_format = "pdf_document",
      output_file = paste0("test_out/", data$Athlete_file_name, "_Report", ".pdf")
    )
  })
```

(same result)

In your code chunk 2 the problem comes when you filter with `Athlete_file_name == Athlete_file_name`. This tests whether these variables are equal *within the dataframe*, i.e. keep every row where the `Athlete_file_name` column equals the `Athlete_file_name` column, which means every row every time! Change the name of the iterating variable to e.g. `in_name`:

```r
for (in_name in Athlete_df$Athlete_file_name) {
...
      filter(Athlete_file_name == in_name) %>%  # twice
...
      output_file = paste0("test_out/", in_name,
      "_Report_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback everyone, there was an error in the for loop. The solution is as follows:

'''

```
#libraries
 library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)

 #extra information
Folder_path1 <- "path to folder"
Excel_sheet1 <- "Data"
StartDate1 <- "2021-09-01"
 EndDate1 <- Sys.Date()

#create athlete dataframe to run one, or multiple athlete reports at once. 
Athlete_full_name <- c("John Smith", "Joe Tree") #as the name should appear in the report
Athlete_file_name <- c("SmithJ", "TreeJ") #Last name, first initial 
Athlete_Team <- c("Men's Football", "Men's Darts") #Sport as it should appear in the report

 Athlete_df <- data.frame(Athlete_full_name, Athlete_file_name, Athlete_Team)
 Names <- unique(Athlete_df$Athlete_file_name)

 #For loop - each athlete in Athlete_df gets unique report

 for (i in Names) {
   #creating new variables for each iteration

   #determine athlete full name
    Athlete_full_name_i <- Athlete_df %>% 
                           filter(Athlete_file_name == i) %>% 
                           subset(select = 1)

#determine athlete sport
   Athlete_Sport_i <-    Athlete_df %>% 
                         filter(Athlete_file_name == i) %>% 
                         subset(select = 3)

 #create Athlete report with unique params and unique filename
   rmarkdown::render("R2S_Dinos_JumpV3.Rmd", 
                 params = list(Athlete_csvname = i,
                               Athlete_fullname = Athlete_full_name_i,
                               Team = Athlete_Sport_i,
                               Folder_path = Folder_path1,
                               Excel_sheet = Excel_sheet1,
                               StartDate = StartDate1,
                               EndDate = EndDate1),
                output_format = "pdf_document",
                output_file=paste0("Athlete Reports/", i, "_Report_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"))
 }
```